# How to handle a Solidity uint array with web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I am facing some problems when accessing elements of an array of uints, returned by a Solidity function, with web3 resp. Javascript.

The signature of my Solidity function looks like this

```
function getSomeIds() public view returns (uint[])
```

Now after I created some elements within my contract, and run above function in the interactive Truffle console I get the following (which is perfectly correct):

```
$ app.getSomeIds()
  [BigNumber {s:1, e:0, c[1]},
   BigNumber {s:1, e:0, c[0]}]
```

The problem with this is, that I cannot access elements of the returned array the common way, since web3 does not receive it as an array but as an object

```
$ array = app.getSomeIds()
$ array[0]
  undefined

$ typeof(array)
  'object'
```

So how can I access the elements of the array?

Comment: Are you surely working with web3 in latter example? In web3, contract functions are called somewhat like this `contractInstance.methods.nameOfContractMethod().call()`. Note that call() is async, so you need to properly handle the asynchronicity.

Comment: @PatrikStas I get the contract instance like this: `ContactId.deployed().then(function(instance){ app = instance})` After this I can call contract functions like I did above in the truffle console.